# 800W non-modular PSU splitting

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, pci-express

I am case-swapping an HP Omen 30L desktop that came with an 800w psu. According to the PSU label, the 12v rail can support up-to 60A. PSU is non-modular and it has 2x8 pin PCIe connectors.

Would it be safe to put a proper gauge Y splitters on each 8-pin PCIe wire to power two graphic cards drawing about 350w max each? (Typically only about 240w each)

[image]

Comment: If you split in two circuits, 30 A requires #10 wire and the T joint needs to be equally heavy. It would seem better to replace with a proper power supply.

Comment: I second Johns suggestion. Much better to get a bigger PSU than burning your house down. 12V * 60A = 720W that means there are only 20W left for all the other components needing 12V supply.